# Changing CarrierWave file upload location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, carrierwave

I want to change the default location where files are saved when using CarrierWave gem. Currently the files are stored in `public/uploads/userfile/avatar/MODELID`. I want to change the location according to the user that is signed it.

For example is User 1 is signed in, the files should be stored to,
`public/uploads/USERID/MODELID`

I changed the avatar_uploader.rb to this:

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{current_user.id}/#{model.id}"
end
```

I am getting an error saying current_user is not found. Any help/clarification would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: on what model did you put "mount_uploader" and how is that model related to the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uploaders (as well as the models) have no idea of the `current_user` variable made by devise, that only works for controllers and views.

The way I would solve that would be to empty your `store_dir` method:

```
def store_dir
    ""
end
```

And then go to your controller and assign your preferred key to the "key" attribute of your uploader object:

```
@uploader = @model.uploader_mounted_as
@uploader.key = "uploads\/#{current_user.id}\/#{model.id}/\${filename}"
```

This will store your upload to `"uploads/1/2/image.png"` if the file is `image.png` your current_user has id `1`, and the model instance has id `2`.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this minutes after posting the question. The rays of brilliance always come at the wrong time!

Here it is,

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.user_id}"
end
```